# Generate different elements with an if statement

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

I have used the following javascript code to generate different numbers if the last letter of an element is a letter or 1. But somehow the whole time else is executed whether it includes letters or not. Where is my mistake??

```
if (document.getElementById(element)!=null && element.charAt(element.length-1)==/^[a-zA-Z]*$/) {
    var element = element+1;
}
else if (element.charAt(element.length-1)==1) {
    var element = element;
    var lastletter = element.charAt(element.length-1);
    lastletter++;
    var element = element.substring(0, element.length-1)+lastletter;
}
else {
    var element = element;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `match` to find substing with regular expression.

**Fixed code:**

```
if (document.getElementById(element) && 
    element.match(/[A-z]$/) { // <========
    var element = element+1;
}
else if (element[element.length - 1]) === '1') {  // <========
    var element = element;
    var lastletter = element.charAt(element.length-1);
    lastletter++;
    var element = element.substring(0, element.length-1)+lastletter;
}
else {
    var element = element;
}​
```

Note that your variable naming are confusing. you better change from `element` to `elementId`.

Comment: `1 == '1'`, so using `1` is ok as long as it's not a strict comparison (`===`), although arguably using `'1'` would be better practice.

Comment: Now the if statement is constantly executed when the element includes a letter but I want it only to be executed when the last character of the element is a letter. How can I achieve that???

Comment: @PhilippBraun. did you copy it right? It's [working fine in my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mY84x/)